# Connection String to start Storefront

Tags: virtocommerce

I have deployed the Virto Commerce Manager to IIS successfully. However when I build the website and start Storefront I get an error when I click Let's Start.
[image]

What should the connectionString be in my Web.config? 
I tried:
"http://localhost/admin/api/"

Comment: Which error do you get when clicking the Let's start?

Comment: Just the error url in the address bar

Answer (score 1):

For the default installation should be http://localhost/admin/api/. Can you open the admin site? It looks like you trying to access /admin and it is not opening and it also looks like you running using IIS Express intead of just IIS.

How did you setup Virto Commerce (which guide or approach did you use)?

Comment: Yes I can open the admin site at http://localhost/admin. I followed the steps in http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Source+Code+Getting+Started. Maybe I need to force the Storefront to deploy with IIS instead of IISExpress?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is correct, but the Let's start link is not. It should point to the absolute URL http://localhost/admin while it points to relative /admin instead, so the full link is http://localhost:53032/admin and it is invalid.

You can navigate to http://localhost/admin manually and import the sample catalog. After that the storefront should show the home page with products.